# Why is this jQuery removing options from WooCommerce select field on cart, but not at checkout?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've managed to put together the below code, which works on my cart page and removes the options I've listed, but doesn't seem to work on my checkout page. I definitely have the page ID correct, the code prints in my footer, but just doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$subt = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
if ((is_page(5) && ( $subt > 30)) || (is_page(6) && ( $subt > 30))) { ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("select#shipping_method_0 option[value='royal_mail:first-class'], select#shipping_method_0 option[value='royal_mail:second-class'] ").remove();
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you any errors in the console inspector?

Comment: Where did did you add this code? Did you confirm it Is running on the checkout page? Are you sure the selectors are the same?

Comment: The selectors are identical, both selects are #shipping_method_0 and I can see the code printed in the footer. For the moment, I've just dropped the code in footer.php